# Check if point is inside circle in openlayers 3 and mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, maps, openlayers-3

In database I have current user, his location and radius of search. So I'm querying other users that are in current user's radius:

```
User.find({
    location: {
         $geoWithin: {
               $centerSphere: [currentUser.location, toRadians(currentUser.radius)]
         }
    }
});
```

Location has `2d` index.

On client side, I draw a circle with `currentUser.radius`:

```
circle.setRadius(radius);
```

So there is a mismatch, on the map second user's point is outside of circle, but mongodb query still thinks that second user is inside the circle. I think I have to convert `currentUser.radius` to something else. Need help

Comment: Depends on how you stored the data in MongoDB, and notably you do not show that here. If the data is in legacy co-ordinate pairs then the distance is indeed in radians. If however the data is stored in GeoJSON format, then distances are in "meters" as is compliant with the spec. Also considering you have in index in place then a `$near` with `$maxDistance` would generally be far more efficient to search with.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks for response, location is stored as [longitude, latitude], radius is stored in meters.

Comment: In which case then the distance should indeed be presented to the query in radians. So what is the `toRadians()` function doing? What is the logic there to return the "meters" input as "radians".

Comment: @BlakesSeven `function toRadians(meters) {
      var miles = meters * 0.000621371192;
      return miles / 3963.2;
}`